# what's the difference between free's result and dmidecode's result in linux?

Tags: linux, memory

I use two tools to collect my memory info, the dmidecode and free, and the two show different results,the dmidecode show my memory is 4096MB, the free -m show's 3829, what it's different and why?

```
Handle 0x0083, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0082
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Total Width: 32 bits
        Data Width: 32 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: RAM slot #0
        Bank Locator: RAM slot #0
        Type: DRAM
        Type Detail: EDO
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
```

`free -m` output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3829       3566        262          0        495       1779
-/+ buffers/cache:       1291       2537
Swap:         8191          0       8191
```

Comment: There's probably some amount taken for video RAM. But since this isn't a programming question, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

`dmidecode` uses BIOS facilities ([smbios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) in particular) to get amount of memory physically present in a system. On system's boot BIOS determines its size from SPD chips on DIMM modules.

But during boot some memory is reserved by BIOS itself (i.e. for Video RAM of embedded videocard), so amount of memory presented to OS is a bit smaller, that is what you see in `free` output.

Usually you can check it from `dmesg` output:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009e000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009e000 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bd92a000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bd92a000 - 00000000bd94c000 (ACPI NVS)
...
```

Comment: Also, the kernel uses a certain amount for it's code, page tables, and other data structures, and these reserved (and typically non-pageable) segments are not reported by `free`, which reports on the amount of memory usable by user space...

Comment: @twalberg: no, memory that is used by kernel doesn't affect MemTotal.